# Requesting public metrics twitter using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter

I have completing my token such as consumer token, secret token, until bearer token. After that I would like to requesting metrics using those tokens but I don't know how to translate the script below into python script.

`curl 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets?ids=1204084171334832128&tweet.fields=public_metrics&expansions=attachments.media_keys&media.fields=public_metrics' --header 'Authorization: Bearer $BEARER_TOKEN'`

I got the information to fetch engagement data from  this https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/metrics

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the requests module.

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets'
params = {
    'ids': '1204084171334832128', 
    'tweet.fields': 'public_metrics',
    'expansions': 'attachments.media_keys',
    'media.fields': 'public_metrics'
}
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer $BEARER_TOKEN'}

r = requests.get(url, data=params, headers=headers)
```